# redirect 301 for crawl with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, google-crawlers

is this code correct for `crawl` pagination to tell search engine to not index url with `?page=1` but index the main of that page.

but i dont want to redirect user to another page. just for `crawl`.

for example

dont index `myweb.org/?page=2` but index as `myweb.org/`

dont index `myweb.org/category/?page=2` but index as `myweb.org/category/`

dont index `myweb.org/12331/namepost/?page=2` but index as `myweb.org/12331/namepost/`

my code for crawl

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/?page=(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]` and

`RewriteRule ^(.*)?page=(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]` without `slash`.

here my full .htaccess.

```
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
            RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$    view.php?cat=$1&idp=$2&post=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}   [NC,L]
             RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}   [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?page=(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?page=(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

            # To externally redirect /dir/abc.php to /dir/abc
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
            RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]


    </IfModule>

    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.piratefiles.org/404.php
    Options -Indexes
```

Comment: I don’t see how that would even begin to make sense. What do you mean by “index as”? Are you trying to make the search engine believe the URL it is currently finding content under (`?page=2`)  was actually a different URL?

Comment: i dont want search engine index url with `?page=xxx` cause it will showing as duplicate, i want all `?page=xxx` index for their main page. for example `myweb.org?page=2` main page is `myweb.org`. `?page=xxx` auto generate from pagination page. sorry for my english.

Comment: Well then I’d output a proper `robots` meta tag (`noindex,follow` or sth. like that) in those pages …

Comment: im already set robots.txt for `Disallow /?page=` and `Disallow /&page=` but how about page already count as duplicate? is there will fix in some days?